# What does #!/bin/bash set -o pipefail if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] if [ $? -eq 0 ] mean in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I am going through one script and found this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: Do you know what `$#` is? What `[[ ]]` means? What `-ne` means inside it?

Answer (score 1):

`$#` is "amount" of positional parameters

example:

```
./script.sh foo bar
```

here we have **2** positional parameters (foo and bar)

***this code checks if positional parameters "count" is not 1***